# helm uninstall chart does not delete associated k8s components

Tags: kubernetes-helm, minikube

I'm using helm charts on minikube. I noticed that when executing `helm uninstall` it does not delete the associated k8s components.  Is this as expected ? if not how do I get it to delete the associated components.  Ideally I want to just update certain components when I do an update, how do I get this done?

Comment: The standard Helm behavior on `helm update` is to only change what has changed; and the standard Kubernetes behavior is that resubmitting an identical object to one that already exists doesn't do anything.  On the flip side, `helm delete` should in fact delete the cluster resources.  Do you have a more complete example of a chart that's not behaving as you expect?

Comment: Can you list k8s components associated with the release that did not get deleted when you run helm uninstall or share chart used so I can test it on my environment ?
For more information on k8s component updates refer to [Automatically Roll Deployments](https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#automatically-roll-deployments)

Comment: I have the same issue in microk8s https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75101715/helm-uninstall-does-not-delete-all-resources-in-microkubernetes